# Already connected: but no output

Tags: java, eclipse, url, post, outputstream

```
URL url2 = new URL("https://win-artl-dev.my.com/rap/opu/odata/ACNLQD/ALPS_SRV/CourseSet");
                HttpURLConnection connection2 = (HttpURLConnection) url2.openConnection();
                connection2.setDoOutput(true);
                //connection2.setRequestMethod("POST");
                OutputStream os = connection2.getOutputStream();
                connection2.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                connection2.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"); 
                connection2.setRequestProperty("x-csrf-token", server);
                osw.write("{\n" + 
                        "   \"Eid\": \""+content+"\",\n" + 
                        "   \"CourseId\": \""+content2+"\",\n" + 
                        "   \"ActId\": \""+content3+"\",\n" + 
                        "   \"PrgNme\": \""+content4+"\",\n" + 
                        "   \"Status\": \""+content7+"\",\n" + 
                        "   \"ChapterID\": \""+content5+"\",\n" + 
                        "   \"UnitID\": \""+content6+"\",\n" + 
                        "   \"Method\": \"GenerateNS\"\n" + 
                        " } ");

                osw.flush();
                //connection2.connect();

                osw.close();
                os.close();  //don't forget to close the OutputStream
                InputStream inputStream = connection2.getErrorStream();
                if (inputStream == null)
                    inputStream = connection2.getInputStream();

                // Read everything from our stream
                BufferedReader responseReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

                String inputLine2;
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

                while ((inputLine2 = responseReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(inputLine2);
                }
                responseReader.close();

                return response.toString();
```

I'm sending the `POST` request that is given abov

- with token
- POST
- body

my problem is it keep saying that I am connected but returning no output.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already connected

I want to see the output or the response of the page.

Can Anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're sending `POST` request. But in your code `setRequestMethod('POST')` is commented?

Answer (score 0):

Move setting the requests properties before getting the output stream. When you get the output stream the connection is open and you get that exception.

```
                //These two go above the getOutputStream()
                connection2.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
                connection2.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                OutputStream os = connection2.getOutputStream();

                OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"); 
                connection2.setRequestProperty("x-csrf-token", server);
```

That's for that exception :) I still can't guarantee your code will work though